# Why does Map.get() return undefined when I know for a fact when logged the item is there?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, methods

I'm curious if I'm missing something here -- When I call a method that should get something from the collection because I have proof it exists, it doesn't get it still
My Object of Collections

```
export const databaseCache = {
  /* Other collections ommitted */
  roles: new Collection<string, Role>(),
};
```

My method

```
export function getRoleByName(name: string) {
  return databaseCache.roles.get(name);
}
```

and my call

```
const feedbackMod = getRoleByName("pack feedback helper");
```

feedbackMod is undefined even though I have proof it exists because I logged the collection, (collection is considered a Map object as Collection is a class that extends Map)

*https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8ITC.jpg image of proof of collection item existing*

Reproduceable Code:

```
interface Role {
    name: string;
    roleId: number;
}

const myCollections = {
    roles: new Map<string, Role>()
};

myCollections.roles.set("pack feedback helper", { name: "pack feedback helper", roleId: 543576460363956244 });
const item = myCollections.roles.get("pack feedback helper");

console.log(item);
```

Although when tested online, this works, locally it does not for me.

Comment: Where and more importantly, do you _"log the collection"_? When do you call `getRoleByName()` relative to this _logging_?

Comment: I log the collection when my client starts up, there is a section of code where I load the items into the collection upon startup and that is where I logged it. Let me know if you need that code or anything else similar

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link to code)](//tsplay.dev/wQAG1w), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing (so no undeclared dependencies like `Collection`; if it's like a `Map`, use `Map` for the example; and in the example, it *is* `undefined`). This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: `Map<K, V>`'s `get()` method's [type signature in the TypeScript library](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/9136bb13fe505d909c8d0e2db4c298c41f184ae8/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts#L25) returns `V | undefined`, so that's the short answer to the question.  Given that `randomMap.get("someRandomKey")` is quite likely to return `undefined`, the type `V | undefined` is a reasonable return type for a compiler that is not omniscient (e.g., how would the compiler know which keys have values and which do not?). Possibly there's more nuance to your question, though, if you can produce a good [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, my first comment was meant to read _"Where and more importantly, **when** do you "log the collection"?"_

Comment: @Phil As soon as the client is initialized and starting up (after all items are loaded into the cache from the database)

Comment: _"this works, locally it does not for me"_... are you saying the literal code from your question which [absolutely works online](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHsA2KDeAoZQ5EOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG4CiosIBJAEypAFdSAI2gsAvnjwJ0IWslIBPAMJZsCMMBnVkAXmT4iydtmp8IAd2QBZOAAcAPLXogGAGjQcAfAAoAlHjEWPEUVTDUNLQA6YwhqSOoIMG8AIltEAGtkGAgIbiEM5AALCExbaGT3HGIySmRUguzc-IRM4tLy9xieKgBWABYAZh6AdgA2PtGABgHRgYBOHtGAJj6+5DFfFmlZMGRgSFJdeWVVCHVNWWiOOIZElLSWrJy8grayqGTNyW3qDkjMdAMbz7CCkTZAA) does not work when you run it locally?

Comment: @jcalz I added an equivalent reproduceable code snippet that worked online, yet doesn't work when put into action inside my client so I'm wondering if it has to do more with maybe something on my end? Possibly even the organization or that the functions are declared as lexical and not block scoped?

Comment: @Phil Yeah that's exactly what I mean

Comment: oh, so this doesn't have much to do with TypeScript (or at least, not with the static type system) and is purely a runtime problem, then.  I'll see myself out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer; it is too much code to paste but in short and simple terms it was because some of my methods were lexically scoped, thus being read by the compiler first, where the collection still had no items in it. When I converted the lexical scoped methods to block (es6 arrow functions), everything was able to load in correctly and be used accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly there is something more going on that your example shows.  The *likely* problem is that you have a `String` vs. a `string` kicking around on one side or the other (e. g. an `objectified` string vs. a `primitive` string):

```js
let key = "pack feedback helper";
let memo = new Map();
memo.set(key, "some value here");
memo.get(key); // Works
memo.get("pack feedback helper"); // Works

let objectifiedKey = new String(key);
memo.get(objectifiedKey); // DOES NOT WORK
```

The simplest test to validate that this is the case is to wrap both the `set` and the `get` calls' `key` argument in `String` to de-objectify the key:

```js
// Continuing from the example above
let deObjectifiedKey = String(objectifiedKey);  // Note the lack of `new` here
memo.get(deObjectifiedKey); // WORKS AGAIN!
```

If it is the case that de-objectifying works, then you can trace which side is causing the problem by checking `typeof key`.  It will be `object` for "objectified" values and `string` for primitive ones.

Alternatively, test in another browser.  If it works in one and not another, then you *may* have a browser bug.